# Ajuda para elaborar consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte tabela no MySQL:
cod,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15
os campos d1...d15 estão preenchidos com valores entre 1 e 25 em cada registro. Não há repetição de valores dentro de um registro.
Como posso realizar consultas para encontrar grupos mais frequentes que se repetem nos registros?
Exemplo: identificar quantas vezes o grupo de valores 1,5,10,15,20,25 apareceu nos registros.
Seria possível criar uma consulta genérica para identificar quais grupos tiveram maior frequência?

Answer (score 0):

Diria que esta pesquisa sumariza a informação da tabela de forma a obter o pretendido.

```
SELECT
    case when d1=1 or 
                        d2=1 or 
    (...) 
                        d15=1
    then 1
    else 0 as dx1 count,
    case when d1=2 or
                         d2=2 or
     (...)
      then 1
      else 0 as dx2 count
(.....) 
from {table} ;
```